When I do a 'git log' command how do I remove non-master branch commits from the output?
This seems like a simple request. When I do a simple 'git log --decorate' while in the master branch .. why do I see all these commits for completely ancillary branches I don't care about?
Is there a way to filter that out?
Previously I ran 'git log --decorate' and would notice side branch commits and that would clutter up some analysis I was trying to do.

git log does not show "the commits on the current branch" (whatever that should mean), but all commits that lead up to the current HEAD (which is also master in this case). It seems that there are some commits in this history that you consider "on ancilliary branches". If you do not want to see them, you can filter them out with, e.g., git log --decorate master ^otherbranch.

The problem is that after a merge, those commits from the "ancillary" branches are also now on the master branch. Try saying
git log --first-parent --oneline --graph --decorate

This will keep Git from following the second parent (in addition to the first parent) every time it encounters a merge commit.
Plus, the wonderful thing about --graph is that if you do encounter a merge commit and follow the second parent, you will know it. git log all by itself is pretty useless because you don't know the topology. --graph shows the topology.

This command is so useful to me that I maintain an alias for it.

I don't understand how --graph helps when also using --first-parent?

I guess I just like the way it looks

Hehe. I agree graph looks slightly better even on linear branches due to those nice pipes, though with --oneline thrown in I think you only get the asterisks.  ;) Regardless, this ought to be a pretty good explanation and solution for OP's ask.

Good point about the oneline.

When using git log to view the history(*) of your repo, I warmly suggest to always include --graph. That way, you will see what commits are merge commits, and probably get a way better view of why a branch comes up in your history.
# try the following two commands:
git log --graph --decorate
git log --graph --oneline --decorate

As far as filtering goes: check the --decorate-refs option
# will keep only local branches (not remote branches, not tags)
git log --decorate --decorate-refs=refs/heads
# will keep only 'master' and tags looking like v-*:
git log --decorate --decorate-refs=refs/heads/master --decorate-refs="refs/tags/v-*"
# will keep only your current, active branch (if any)
git log --decorate --decorate-refs=refs/heads/$(git branch --show-current)


(*) as opposed to: using git log to extract information for scripting purpose.
